# Open specific page when taskbar icon is clicked for a chrome extension with background permission declared

Tags: google-chrome-extension

After declaring `"permissions": ["background"]` for a chrome extension, there will be an icon located at system taskbar (windows). When clicking that icon, by default, `chrome://extensions` page will be opened. Is there any way to overwrite this behavior, such as opening other pages instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*apps* can specify it in manifest `"app": {"launch": "local_path": "..."}}` (or `"web_url": "..."`),
*extensions* don't have it, so Chrome uses a [fallback](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/extensions/application_launch.cc?cl=GROK&gsn=OpenApplication&l=142):

1. [Options page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options) of the extension is opened if specified in manifest
2. `chrome://extensions` is opened otherwise

FWIW, *apps* can also use [chrome.app.runtime API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_runtime) for this purpose.

Comment: Cool! `options` page is enough for my purpose.